# Methods that return a value and System.in methods

Tags: java

I am working on a project in Java to draw trees. I have to make a public static Scanner class object that is connected to the System.in console input device. As a class object, it is supposed to be the scope for all methods in this class. To top that off, I have to have a method under the name of getAttribute with the header:

public static int getAttribute (String prompt)

The "main" will call the getAttribute twice, once for the number of segments in the tree (in this case, 3) and the second for the height of the segments (4). For this tree, the fill character is *. Basically, the first sample tree is:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
     *
     *
  *******
```

My coding so far is:

```
public class DrawTrees {
   public static final int SubHeight = 4 ;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int line = 1; line <= SubHeight; line++) {
         writeSpaces(6 - line) ;
         System.out.print("*") ;
      }
   }
   public static void writeSpaces(int = 6)
      for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
   }
}


      double getAttribute(double Height);
      double getAttribute(double Segments);
   }

   System.out.println(*){
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`enter code here`
   String username = scanner.nextLine();
   System.out.println();
   }

   public static int getAttribute(double Height = 4)
   public static int getAttribute(double Segments = 3)
```

I have the three paragraphs on the bottom because I know I need them, but have not figured out how and where they fit in.
Currently, my main focus is getting the "writeSpaces" method to work, but I keep getting this error:
DrawTrees.java:12: error:  expected
   public static void writeSpaces(int = 6)
                                     ^
I know this is a lot, but I have tried and tried, yet nothing has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you provided is what your using then there are a lot of syntax errors. Here is your code free of syntax errors.

```
public class DrawTrees {
   public static final int SubHeight = 4 ;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int line = 1; line <= SubHeight; line++) {
         writeSpaces(6 - line) ;
         System.out.print("*") ;
      }

    System.out.println(*);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String username = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
   }

   public static int getAttribute(double height){

   }
   public static void writeSpaces(int spaces){
      for (int i = 1; i <= spaces; i++){
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
   }
}
```

This is not a solution to project, just a fix to the original error. Something you need to look up is proper method creation in Java. The code you provided suggests that you don't have a strong grip on syntax yet but your IDE should help you fix most of these errors.

As a brief overview here are somethings to concern when making a method.

1) Each method has a head and a body.

```
public static void main(String[] args)///the head
{
   ///the body
}
```

2) The head is used to state the access level, whether it's static/non-static, the return, the name, and the parameters for the method.

3) Parameters must be declared the same way variables are declared.

```
public void foo(int number) ///[datatype] int [variable name] number
```

4) The body of a method begins and ends with curly brackets *{}*

Take your time with your project and make sure you're able to get a solid understanding of how to write the code while you think of your solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your method signature for writeSpaces().

Change it to:

```
public static void writeSpaces(int n)
```

Where n is number of spaces you want to print.